# SAS macro modification

Tags: sas

I have two values which represent dates:

```
 a=101 and b=103
```

Below is first  macro saved in separate file `one.sas`:

```
 %global time nmall;
 %let nmall =;
 %macro pmall;
 %do i=&a. %to &b;
 %if &i =&a. then %do;
 %let nmall=&nmall.&i;
 %end;
 %else %let nmall=&nmall.,&i;
 end;
 %put (&nmall);
 %mend;

 %pmall;
```

So above `pmall` give me values `101,102,103`.

Below is second macro:

```
%include “one.as”;

%macro c(a=,b=);
%let m=;
%let m1=;
%do i =&a %to &b;
%let o=&i;

proc sql;
 create table new&o as select * from data where nb in(&o.);quit;

%let m =&m.date&o;

data date&o.;
set date&o.;
if pass =&o.;
run;

proc sort data=date&o.;
by flag;
end;

data output &a._&b.;
set &m;
%mend;
```

The above macro creates three datasets `date101` `date102` and `date 103`, then append it to `output101_103`.

I am trying to modify above macros in such a way that I will not use `%macro` and `%mend` approach. Below is the modified macro code:

```
data a_to_c;
do o=&a to &c;
output;
end;
run;
```

so above code will have values `101 102 103` in variable `o` for  dataset `a_to_c`.

```
 data _null_;
 set a_to_c;
 call execute ('create table new’||strip(o)||' as select * from data 
 where nb in(’||strip(o)||' );quit;’);
 run;
```

I want to know how to do below things.

1. Create `pmall` values in a macro variable in my modified  macro inside the data step `data a_to_c`, so that I can use it further.

How to proceed from `%let m` macro in the first macro code to new code which I am developing above.

Comment: I really have no idea what you are asking for. (1) Why do you want to split your data into lots of small datasets and then put them back together? (2) What difference does it make how you do it?

Comment: I dont want to put everything between %macro and %mend. Splitting to analyse the data further.

Comment: If you don't want a macro then don't use one.  So WHAT is the question.

Comment: I am looking how to create pmall value and append process in the new code which I am working on. Since the iteration happening within %macro and %mend. So i  created a new dataset to get the iteration value and use call execute function. Now main i need to know how to create pmall and appending process.

Comment: You can use a macro to generate code. You could use a data step to generate code. Either using CALL EXECUTE like in your example, or just writing the code to a file to be run using %include later.  If you want to dynamically create multiple dataset from one then look at using a hash object.

Comment: What is *pmall*? Is it the macro that you don't want to create? Is it the list of value separated by commas? That you could create as a macro variable from within a data step.  Is it a dataset? A variable? The name of some analysis technique you want to run?

Comment: It is best to describe the problem you are trying to solve. Give input and output data so we understand what you want.  If the problem is to generate code then give examples code you want to generate.  It is beginning to sound to me like you really do want a macro with a parameter.  Is the problem that you have some other macro that you are running that you cannot modify and you want some way to deal with the outputs that it creates?

Comment: Pmall is macro variable which will have list of values separated by commas. In my modify macro, i want to create pmall as macro variable in the datastep                                                                                                       data a_to_c;
do o=&a to &c;
output;
end;
run;

Answer (score 1):

> Pmall is macro variable which will have list of values separated by
>   commas. In my modify macro, i want to create pmall as macro variable
>   in the datastep data a_to_c; do o=&a to &c; output; end; run; – geetha
>   anand 1 min ago

To create a macro variable from within a data step using the `CALL SYMPUTX()` function.

```
data a_to_c;
  length pmall $200 ;
  do o=&a to &c; 
    pmall=catx(',',pmall,o);
    output; 
  end; 
  call symputx('pmall',pmall);
  drop pmall;
run;
```

If you really want to generate code without a SAS macro you can use `CALL EXECUTE()` or write the code to a file and use `%INCLUDE` to run it. Or for small pieces of code you could try putting the code in a macro variable, but macro variables can only contain 64K bytes.

It is really hard to tell from what you posted what code you want to generate. Let's assume that you want to generate an new dataset for each value in the sequence and then append that to some aggregate dataset.  So for the first pass through the loop your code might be as simple as these two steps. First to create the proper subset in the right order and the second to append the result to the aggregate dataset.

```
proc sort data=nb out=date101 ;
  where nb=101 ;
  by flag ;
run;

proc append base=date101_103 data=date101 force;
run;
```

Then next two times through the loop will look the same only the "101" will be replaced by the current value in the sequence.

So using CALL EXECUTE your program might look like:

```
%let a=101;
%let c=103;
proc delete data=date&a._&c ;
run;
data _null_;
  do nb=&a to &c; 
    call execute(catx(' ','proc sort data=nb out=',cats('date',nb,'),';'));
    call execute(cats('where nb=',nb,';')) ;
    call execute('by flag; run;');
    call execute("proc append base=date&a._&c data=");
    call execute(cats('date',nb));
    call execute(' force; run;');
  end;
run;
```

Writing it to a file to run via %INCLUDE would look like this:

```
filename code temp ;
data _null_;
  file code ;
  do nb=&a to &c; 
    put 'proc sort data=nb out=date' nb ';'
      / '  where ' nb= ';'
      / '  by flag;'
      / ';'
      / "proc append base=date&a._&c data=date" nb 'force;'
      / 'run;'
    ;
  end;
run;
proc delete data=date&a._&c ;
run;
%include code / source2;
```

If the goal is to just create the aggregate dataset and you do not need to keep the smaller intermediate datasets then you could just use the same name for the intermediate dataset on each pass through the loop.  That will make the code generation easier as then there is only only place that needs to change based on the current value.  Also that way you only need to have two dataset names even for a sequence of 10 or 20 values.  It will take less space and reduce clutter in the work library.

Comment: Thanks for that. The other question i have is, when i run data _null_ step in my code, it creates three datasets new101 new 102 and new103. Now i want to  create new dataset output &a._&b. by appending datasets new’||strip(o)||.

Comment: A data \_null_ step doesn't create datasets.  Perhaps you want to generate another macro variable with the list of dataset names? Then use that in the step to append them.

Comment: data output &a._&b.;set a_to_c;
 call execute ('set ’||strip(o)||'';);
run;                                                                                                                                                    does this works?

Comment: No. (1) you cannot run a `set` statement by itself. So you need to generate a `data` statement also. (2) `set a; set b;` is totally different than `set a b;` .

Comment: Why can’t we use proc append instead of set?

Comment: But how to create new dataset in proc append and iterate the appending datasets

Comment: Added code to show how to use PROC APPEND at the end of the generated code so that each loop iteration appends its results to the aggregate output dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Geetha:

I think you will find the macro-ization of the process to be far easier if you go from a data-centric explicit solution and proceed abstracting the salient features into macro symbols (aka variables)

The end run solution appears to be:

```
data output_101_to_103;
  set original_data;
  where nb between 101 and 103;
run;
proc sort data=output_101_to_103;
  by nb flag;
run;
```

In which case you could code a macro that abstracts 101 to FIRST and 103 to LAST.  The data sets could also be abstracted.  The abstracted parts are specified as the macro parameters.

```
%macro subsetter(DATA=, FIRST=, LAST, OUTPREFIX=OUTPUT);
  %local out;
  %let out = &OUTPREFIX._&FIRST._&LAST.;

  data &out;
    set &DATA.;
    where nb between &FIRST. and &LAST.;
    * condition = "between &FIRST. and &LAST."; * uncomment if you want to carry along the condition into your output data set;
  run;
  proc sort data=&out;
    by nb flag;
  run;
%mend;
```

And use as

```
%subsetter (data=original_data, first=101, last=103, outprefix=output)
```

Note: If you did keep the `condition` variable in the output data, you WOULD NOT be able to use it directly as a source code statement in a future data step, as in <strike>`if nb condition then ...`</strike>

I suppose you could also pass the NB and FLAG as parameters -- but you approach a point of diminishing returns on the utility of the macro.

Macro-izing the specific example I showed doesn't make too much sense unless you need to perform a lot of different variations of FIRST and LAST in a well documented framework.  Sometimes it is just better to not abstract the code and work with the specific cases.  Why? Because when there are too many abstracted pieces the macro invocation is almost as long as the specific code you are generating and the abstraction just gets in the way of understanding.

If the macro is simply chopping up data and reassembling data, you might be better served rethinking the flow using where, by, and class statements and abstracting around that.